# Publish/Unpublish item based on the conditions automatically

Tags: publishing

**Environment:** Sitecore 9.2 & SXA 1.8

I have an `Item` that has been used as a parameter in multiple items.

For example, `Item A` has been used in `Item B`, `Item C`, and `Item D`.

If `Item A` is used in multiple items (more than one item) at the same time, it should be publishable otherwise it shouldn't. 
If `Item A` is used in multiple items and content editor removes it from all the items except one, then it must be unpublished immediately.

How to publish/unpublish `Item A` on the basis of items that reference it.

Comment: I think you have to extend the publishing pipeline for conditional publishing and need to add Workflow specific to this, which can help you in identifying to pick up the items for processing.